# Necessary torque of motor to move a door.

Tags: motor

I am building an automatic door opener and for its mechanism I need a motor with a high torque and low speed. My question here is how to measure the torque needed to move the door as I cannot really weigh the door and find its mass. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ask a moderator to change this to Electronics.stackexchange.

Comment: This is more of a question about applied physics, and not about electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "hanging scale" preferably "analog one".

[image: hanging scale]

Mount it to any place of the door and slowly pool at 90 degrees. Check what value does the scale show when doors start moving. Static friction is always higher than dynamic friction.

[Torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque) = Radius * Force

Raduis is the distance between mounting place and door hinges.
Force is 9.81 times max value shown by the scale in kilograms.

Do this many times for many mounting points then take average.
Use safety margin of 50% (motor should have at least 150% of required torque)